# Strange behavior of Markdown with links in comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, formatting

I don't know if you're using a customized version of Markdown on this site, but it behaves really strangely in the comments. For example, here is the proper behaviour on questions and answers: [*emphasis inside link*](https://english.stackexchange.com/), *[emphasis outside link](https://english.stackexchange.com/)*, [[brackets around link](https://english.stackexchange.com/)]. See below for the corresponding behaviour in comments.

Comment: Here is the broken behaviour in comments: [*emphasis inside link*](http://english.stackexchange.com/), *[emphasis outside link](http://english.stackexchange.com/)*, [[brackets around link](http://english.stackexchange.com/)].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Comments don't use Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities). You can put very limited formatting in comments — `*italic*` and `**bold**` —, but even that is likely to break if there isn't whitespace before/after the highlighted word. (So you can't italicize part of a word in comments.)

Comment: I will add to this that there's a [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/) over at the meta Meta, where you can try things out before actually posting them on an SE site.